# Is is possible to sort EF query results in the database using "Array.IndexOf" or other code-derived data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, .net-4.8

The following code works, while needing to have the result fetched from the database first:

```
// ID's by priority (arbitrary yet limited number; eg. 1 to 10 values)
var ids = new [] { 3, 1, 2 };

// Should return "item 3" if it exists, else "item 1", else "item 2"..
var firstItemByPriority = context.Items
    .Where(i => ids.Contains(i.Id))
    .ToList() // materialize DB results
    .OrderBy(i => Array.IndexOf(ids, i.Id))
    .FirstOrDefault(); // ie. TOP 1 / LIMIT 1 / First (by ordering)
```

Is there a way to write this in a way where the ordering can occur *in* the generated database query? (Such can be constructed in several different ways when writing SQL manually.)

While the example above uses `Array.IndexOf`, the general goal is to sort by derived data *not in the database*. Using SQL Server specific extensions and/or third-party extensions are fair play.

Comment: Even if you could `Array.IndexOf(ids, i.Id)` is `O(n)` which means your entire loop is `O(n*n)` - that's terrible. I'd have expected someone with your rep-level to grok runtime complexity...

Comment: The ordering of results in SQL doesn't matter - so doing sorting at the client-side is fine. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Convert your `ids` to a dictionary with their index (in `O(n)`) like so: `var sortOrders = ids.Select( ( v, idx ) => ( v, idx ) ).ToDictionary( t.v, t.idx );` then pass that as a Table-Valued Parameter  into your Linq query somehow asssuming your Linq provider supports it (fun fact: they don't), which is why you need to do it client-side - but use the dictionary instead of `Array.IndexOf` because that will give you awful performance.

Comment: Big-O describes behavior as a system becomes very large. If N is small as stated in the problem, O(N^2) performance isn't likely to matter (if you can afford the DB query, the sorting time will be relatively tiny), and the dictionary-based solution may perform similarly to an array scan anyhow for very small N.

Comment: For me .OrderBy(i => Array.IndexOf(ids, i.Id)) doesn't make any sense at all , I can not even imagine how it could be done. Doesn't make any sense to order each time when a new item selected, since order make sense only for a list but here you take only the first item.

Comment: A small BenchmarkDotNet test, replacing `context.Item` with an array to focus on the difference in `Array.IndexOf()` vs a dictionary lookup yields: `WithArray` 260.5ns, `WithSet` 429.5ns.

Comment: @Serge — note the end result of “First item by given ordering”. The code in the query produces a reliable result. The question is ultimately about moving the order by (and applied limit) into the SQL execution itself. In SQL this could be written with a JOIN to a relation of (ID, index) or with ORDER BY .. CASE (dynamically expanded).

Comment: (And perhaps the answer to this question is that such has never, ever, been done in EF6 since it’s release, anywhere, due to technical limitations (eg. lack of EF extensibility with query generation) or sufficient alternatives. I was hoping to find a clever cookie and a glass of milk.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this efficiently without raw SQL queries, and raw SQL Queries are not composable with LINQ queries in EF6, like they are in EF Core.  But the SQL Query for this is very simple.  So something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

namespace Ef6Test
{

    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }

    }


    public class Db : DbContext
    {
        public Db() : base("server=localhost;database=ef6Test;integrated security=true")
        { }
        public DbSet<Item> Items{ get; set; }
        
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                        .ToTable("Items")
                        .Property(i => i.Id)
                        .HasColumnName("Id")
                        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }


    }

    internal class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);

                if (db.Database.Exists())
                    db.Database.Delete();

                db.Database.Create();

                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 2)
                {
                    var item = new Item() { Id = i, Name = $"Item{i}" };
                    db.Items.Add(item);
                    if (i % 100 == 0)
                        db.SaveChanges();

                }
                db.SaveChanges();

            }

            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.Connection.Open();

                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("create table #ids(position int primary key, id int)");

                var ids = new[] { 3, 1, 12, 5, 8, 10, 7};
                var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(ids);

                var pIds = new SqlParameter("@ids", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
                pIds.Value = json;

                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("insert into #ids(position,id) select [key], [value] from openjson(@ids)", pIds);

                var sql = @"
select top (@count) i.*
from Items i
join #ids ids
  on i.Id=ids.Id
order by ids.position
";
                var pCount = new SqlParameter("@count", 3);
                var results = db.Database.SqlQuery<Item>(sql,pCount).ToList();
                
                foreach (var item in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
                }
              
            }
            Console.WriteLine("complete");
         }
  
        }
    }
```

outputs

```
12
8
10
complete
```

Comment: hmm, what's the performance of passing JSON in an nvarchar param vs. TVPs? Also, doesn't the JSON nvarchar have a max length of 4000 chars?

Comment: Surprisingly good, and no it’s nvarchar(max).